# Best regression for dependent variable bounded [-1,infinity]

Tags: regression, econometrics

I am trying to deal with a regression model estimating a fold change in price of a drug given different explanatory variables (strength, formulation, country, etc..).

My data has quite a lot of zeroes (meaning no fold change) and is bounded between -1 and infinity (potentially).
Would the fact that the data is not normally distributed have an impact on the outcome of a general linear regression?
If this is the case, what is the best regression model for such data generally speaking?
I read some material about two-part models. Would that seem good for my case?

Comment: How do you get a negative ratio of prices? Surely prices are non-negative and their ratio is in [0, $\infty$]?

Comment: @mdewey I get a negative value if there has been a drop in price. It is not just a ratio I am calculating but something like (p1-p2)/p2 assuming p2 being my base price. I have probably used bad wording

Comment: Why not use continuous compounding so growth rates are between negative infinity and infinity?  Otherwise you can add one to all data so the range is between 0 and infinity.

Comment: @www3 thx for your suggestion. My main problem however concerns the choice of the most appropriate regression model. Would the fact of having a lot of zeroes in my values will impact a linear regression model? I am considering the ln() transformation of my y variable so even if I add 1, all my 1s will become zeroes as ln(1)=0.